# NSOperation VS GCD for Core-Data

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

What is more suitable for a situation where data needs to be stored in Core-Data on one thread and read from Core-Data on another?

I was thinking of GCD but how does it work with the creation of the NSManagedObjectContext for each thread? How does one create these objects in a queue?

The data store needs to be updated/synced when changes have been made on various threads, is this better to do with GCD or NSOperation?

I would like to be able to just pass blocks to the 2 queues when reading and writing to the data store as needed, without having issues with corrupting the store or having different versions of the store.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The debate between GCD and `NSOperation` basically boils down to the argument of using the highest level of abstraction that provides you with a good solution.

`NSOperationQueue` is built on top of GCD, so it must be a higher level of abstraction.

However, GCD is so easy to use in the general case, that I find it is preferable to `NSOperationQueue` in many cases.

Now, when you bring CoreData into the mix, I would suggest a third alternative.  If you are using iOS 5, then you can use private queue concurrency with your MOC.  I find that is a good abstraction, and provides an easy to use interface.

So, I would suggest you simply create a MOC with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` for each thread in which you want to do Core Data.  You can choose, based on your application characteristics, whether to share a `persistentStoreCoordinator`, or use a separate one.  You could even use nested contexts (with a caveat for the insert-side).

Basically, it follows this model...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectCotext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueuqConcurrencyType];
moc.parentContext = contextIWantToBeParent;
moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = pscIWant;

[moc performBlock:^{
    // Your MOC stuff running on its own private queue
}];
```

Of course, you must choose one method (either parenting to an existing MOC or attaching to a PSC).

I generally prefer the `performBlock` method.

**EDIT**

> Thanks. I read that NSManagedObject isnt thread safe. How would I
>   create new NSManagedObjects on that private queue? – Helium3

Yes, that is true.  However, when you create a MOC with a concurrency type, you are agreeing to a contract that goes something like this.

I, an astute programmer, do solemnly agree to the following Core Data Rules regarding concurrency:

1. If I use `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`, I will only use it while running on the thread that created it.
2. If I use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, I will only use the MOC from within either `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait`.
3. If I use `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, I will only use the MOC from within either `performBlock`, `performBlockAndWait`, or when I know that I am running on the main thread.

If you follow those rules, then you will be able to use the MOC on other threads.

Specifically, when using `performBlock`, the Core Data API will make sure the code is appropriately synchronized.

Comment: Thanks. I read that NSManagedObject isnt thread safe. How would I create new NSManagedObjects on that private queue?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So if NSManageObjects are added to the store or edited by the MOC with concurrency, there is no need to manually sync the store?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow that question.

Answer (score 1):

All your problems have been solved and more with the new context concurrency types in iOS 5:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/